# Can I use elseif with preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match, sql-injection

So, I'm creating a vulnerability scanner for SQLI that tests individual websites as a sort of free online service.

Anyways, I'm trying to see if when I scan it if it returns text commonly found on vulnerable sites, I'm using preg_match to do this like so:

```
          if(preg_match("You have an error in your SQL','Division by zero in|supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in|Call to a member function','Microsoft JET Database|ODBC Microsoft Access Driver|Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server|Unclosed quotation mark|Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle|Incorrect syntax near|SQL query failed", Connect_Host(str_replace("=", "='", $sites[2][$a])))) {
            echo "Its vulnerable";
          } elseif(preg_match("mysql_num_rows()"||"mysql_fetch_array()"||"Error Occured While Processing Request"||"error"in"your"sql"syntax"||"mysql_fetch_row()"||"VBScript Runtime"||"BOF or EOF"||"mysql_fetch_object()"||"Invalid Querystring", Connect_Host(str_replace("=", "='", $sites[2][$a])))) {
            echo "Its vulnerable";
          } else {
            echo "Its not vulnerable";
            flush(); ob_flush();
          }
```

Anyways, when I run it, I get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\scanner\index.php on line 78

In this case, the code that the error is on (line 78) is the elseif, this is the entire line 78:

```
} elseif(preg_match("mysql_num_rows()"||"mysql_fetch_array()"||"Error Occured While Processing Request"||"error"in"your"sql"syntax"||"mysql_fetch_row()"||"VBScript Runtime"||"BOF or EOF"||"mysql_fetch_object()"||"Invalid Querystring", Connect_Host(str_replace("=", "='", $sites[2][$a])))) {
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use it as soon as you compose correct regular expression. What you have written just makes no sense.

Comment: You should highly consider adding all of your matches in an array and using [`in_array`](http://ca3.php.net/in_array) to see if it matches.

Comment: I admire the attitude, but I think vulnerability testing is neither this simple nor this black and white.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `preg_match();` is a regular expresion, not normal text, so you (probably) need delimiters.

- The first parameter states **what** are you searching for
- The second parameter states **where** are you searching

So, *corrected*, your line should be:

```
} elseif(preg_match("/(mysql_num_rows\(\)|mysql_fetch_array\(\)|Error Occured While Processing Request|error in your sql syntax|mysql_fetch_row\(\)|VBScript Runtime|BOF or EOF|mysql_fetch_object()|Invalid Querystring/i", Connect_Host(str_replace("=", "='", $sites[2][$a]))))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in line number 78 :

```
} elseif(preg_match("/(mysql_num_rows()|mysql_fetch_array()|Error Occured While Processing Request|error in your sql syntax|mysql_fetch_row()|VBScript Runtime|BOF or EOF|mysql_fetch_object()|Invalid Querystring/i", Connect_Host(str_replace("=", "='", $sites[2][$a]))))) {
```